# PHP parses JavaScript content inside heredoc

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables, heredoc

```php
<?php
$javascript = <<<EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
function test () {
    return 'test test test \n test test test';
}
</script>
EOT;

echo $javascript;
?>
```

The \n above is parsed as newline by PHP, generates HTML source like the following

```
    return 'test test test 
 test test test';
```

and this results in a JavaScript syntax error: unterminated string literal.

---

I have a big chunk of JavaScript code, so I don't want to wrap them like

```
$javascript = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\nfunction test()...\n";
```

and actually the JavaScript code is not directly echo'd to the page, it is passed to another function, this is why I need a PHP variable.

---

So how can I define a PHP variable that contains a big chunk of JavaScript code whitout causing problems?

Is there a way like if / endif?

```
<?php if (condition): ?>
html code...
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Use a NOWDOC instead.

Comment: There's a variable in op code, NOWDOC will skip it. Use output buffering.

Comment: @mario changing EOT to 'EOT' works

Comment: show yourself downvoter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Option 1: Use a [NOWDOC](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc), which is to HEREDOCs as `'` single quotes are to `"` double quotes.

```
$javascript = <<<'EOT'
   ...\n...
EOT;
```

Option 2: Escape the special character:

```
$javascript = <<<EOT
    ...\\n...
EOT;
```

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
$javascript = <<<'EOT'
<script type="text/javascript">
$demo = 'test';
alert($demo);
</script>
EOT;
echo $javascript;
```

If i use 'EOT' then my code in javascript working well, but i use EOT then my code will understand $dem is variable in PHP